# How to get Pygame to open images

Tags: python, image, pygame

I've been trying to find a solution to this problem for a while now: I'm trying to display an image using the Pygame module in python but I always get this error:

```
File "C:/Users/Brandon/PycharmProjects/UnstableUnicorns/UnstableUnicorns Test.py", line 13, in <module>
    Baby_Narwhal = pygame.image.load(r"Baby Narwhal.png").convert()
    pygame.error: Couldn't open Baby Narwhal.png
```

(Yes I know there are spaces but there are a lot of images that I want to display and they all have spaces in their names)

I've tried putting the whole path file, using .convert(), using backslashes (and removing the spaces didn't work either) and adding interpreter paths. I've asked this question multiple times on this site and I haven't gotten a working answer. Help.

```
    import pygame
import os
import sys
from time import sleep

print(os.getcwd())

# get the directory of this file
sourceFileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# [...]

Baby_Narwhal = pygame.image.load(r"Baby Narwhal.png").convert()

pygame.init()

xDisplay = 1000
yDisplay = 500

white = (255, 255, 255)

def main():
    display = pygame.display.set_mode((xDisplay, yDisplay))

    while True:
        display.fill(white)

        display.blit(Baby_Narwhal, (0, 0))

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            pygame.display.update()


main()
```

Comment: You've to use the path name in `pygame.image.load`: `pygame.image.load(os.path.join(sourceFileDir, r"Baby Narwhal.png"))`. Of course this will only work if the image file is in the same file as the source file. So where is the image file located on your local drive? By the way you never got the proper answer, because you never provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution would to get the path of the image or whatever you need. I had this problem about a month ago, and getting the exact path fixed it for me. You should also verify that you have the correct name of the file in your code. Hope this helps.. Good luck! :)

Example: ***C:/User/Desktop...***

*(im a linux guy) I don't usually use Windows so I don't know paths off the top of my head. Additionally, you could try and put your pygame file and image into your same folder and just get the name of your image/file.*